# Why are my radiators leaking?

Tags: furnace

I have a gas boiler that seems to have way too much water in it and has pushed the excess water out the vents on my radiators. I have shut it off. It has flooded my main floor. How do I stop this?

Answer (score 3):

Call a plumber.

In my locale, radiator "vents" (bleed valves) should be closed when you are not bleeding air from them (which should only be done with the boiler off). Boilers vent excess water into a header tank, an expansion vessel or other provision - not via radiators.